# Xamairn ToolBarItem change text and icon

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I can't seem to change the text or icon of a ToolBarItem. I have a ContentPage with a ToolBarItem that should change it's text when tapped:

```xml
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="languageButton" Icon="flag.png" Text="EN" Clicked="LanguageButton_Clicked"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

If I set a breakpoint, it steps over the code, and the Text property of the ToolBarItem is changed, but on the device it does not change:

```cs
private void LanguageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (languageButton.Text == "EN")
    {
        languageButton.Text = "NL";
    }
    else
    {
        languageButton.Text = "EN";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code working fine for me. Text getting changed when clicking on it. How are u starting MainPage in App.cs class?

Comment: @IvanIčin - I am not the downvoter :)

Comment: I just test your code and it works in both Android and iOS with latest Xamarin.forms version 4.3.0.991211.

Comment: Thanks for the tests! It seems it needs a clean / rebuild after upgrading before taking effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be 'fixed' in the latest Xamarin.Forms, so try to update to it: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7181